# Using dynamic HTML templates in Meteor emails

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to render a Meteor template as the HTML body of an email?

For example if I want to show collection data or generate dynamic links inside that email.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes this is possible, here I provide a client-side solution to this common problem.

First you should define a simple template that will serve as your email html body :

```
<template name="shareEmailContent">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
</template>
```

Then you can use Email.send (see [Email.send at docs.meteor.com](http://docs.meteor.com/#email_send), you'll need some proper configuration such as adding the email Smart Package and setting `MAIL_URL`) to email the result of the template rendering.
Email.send only works on the server, so you must define a server method callable from the client.

Server side :

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendShareEmail:function(options){
    // you should probably validate options using check before actually
    // sending email
    check(options,{
      from:String,
      // etc...
    });
    Email.send(options);
  }
});
```

Client side :

```
var dataContext={
  message:"You must see this, it's amazing !",
  url:"http://myapp.com/content/amazingstuff",
  title:"Amazing stuff, click me !"
};
var html=Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.shareEmailContent,dataContext);
var options={
  from:"sender@domain.com",
  to:"receiver@domain.com",
  subject:"I want to share this with you !",
  html:html
  })
};
Meteor.call("sendShareEmail",options);
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can also decide to render email templates on the server. Server-side rendering is not yet supported but you can still accomplish it using a third party templating package.

EDIT 06/09/2014 : updated to use the latest `Blaze` API as of Meteor 0.9.1

Comment: The problem is that Template only works on the client side, so this pretty much only is useful if you're willing to have all your email templates be viewable by all your users.

Comment: You are right, if you want to generate your email templates server-side (which makes sense), you'll have to use this package for example : https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-handlebars-server

Comment: yeah that's what i ended up doing. Worked well! But yeah, will be good when it is natively supported in Meteor though.

Comment: For those who want to generate a client side email template in Blaze (>0.8.0), see this https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2007

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect these changes in Blaze APIs, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Meteor 1.0. If you want to send templated emails from your server:

1.Install the meteor package email:

`meteor add email`

`meteor add blaze`

2.Create an email account at [sendgrid](http://www.sendgrid.com) or just get the smtp parameters from your email provider. I didn't test with gmail. But with sendmail, it was straithforward!

3.Configure the smtp settings in /server/smtp.js:

```
Meteor.startup(
function (){
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://<username>:<password>@smtp.sendgrid.net:587';
}
```

);

4.You can use the following on your server.js:

```
myfunction(){
   var html = Blaze.toHTML(Blaze.With(data, function() { return Template.my_template; }));
   Email.send({
            from: "My company name <noreply@mycompany.com>",
            to: "john.doe@gmail.com",
            subject: "Any subject...",
            html: html
        });
   }
```

5.Create your template in /client/template/my_template.html:

```
<template name="my_template">
    Hello <b>{{name}}</b>
</template>
```

Notice that {{name}} here refer to the properties defined in data, defined as data = {name: "John"}. The following template will output as: "Hello **John**", and all the html tags will be saved into the variable html.

6.Call myfunction() anywhere in your server code. Et voilà! The email will be sent. If you don't receive the email, make sure it didn't go into your spam.

This method still need the template to be in the client side.

Comment: `Template` isn't defined on the server?

Comment: We are also getting `Template is not defined`error on server.

Comment: have you guys tried to install SSR package yet? https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr

Comment: Using Meteor 1.3, it worked without installing SSR package. I'm using Blaze Components, but I don't think it's related. Anyway, remember that the email template must be in a folder accessible by the server, obviously.

Comment: I tried this with Meteor 1.3 but I also get a Error Message. Template.xxx -> property xxx could not be found. If I try to include the html Template I get error messages that the module xxx.html can't be found. I tried different locations but nothings seems to work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

accepted answer uses client side code. If you are looking to build email templates client side code can be insecure.
there is a package([meteor-ssr](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr)) for server side rendering templates you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

As @pahan mentioned a server side rendering package might be your best bet. Here is a good tutorial that I used: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-the-email-package