# Meteor: How to use your own mailer template?

Tags: templates, meteor, customization, mailer

Hi guys I have a method like follow:

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (to, from, name, text) {

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        return Meteor.Mandrill.send({
            to: to,
            from: from,
            name: name,
            text: text
        });
    }
  }
});
```

This method is called in my contact.js (the html view is contact.html):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.Contact.events({
    "click .btn": function(event) {
      var from  = document.getElementById('from').value; 
      var name  = document.getElementById('name').value;
      var text  = document.getElementById('message').value;

  Meteor.call('sendEmail', 'lolotutu@gmail.com', from, name, text);

    }
  });

  Template.Contact.helpers({
    test: "Working"
  });
```

Everything work fine, however I have no control over the template used to send the mail. I am using Mandrill here and I would like to know how to tell my `sendEmail` method to serve a custom template to be sent to people. Maybe something with `Session.set` and `Session.get` but I have trouble implementing it. Thanks.

Comment: Saimeunt give a great example [on this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845932/using-dynamic-html-templates-in-meteor) check it out

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I got it now !

Answer (score -1):

For a defined template called yourcustomtemplate.html, you can use the following:

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (to, from, name, text) {

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        return Meteor.Mandrill.send({
            to: to,
            from: from,
            name: name,
            text: text,
            html: function(user,url){return Spacebars.toHTML({user: user.name, url: url}, Assets.getText('yourcustomtemplate.html'))}
        });
    }
  }
});
```

The email will be formated to be sent as html, with the text as the backup for viewer which cannot view html.