# email a html page report for printing

Tags: html, meteor, printing

After downloading a page from the web using HTTP, this Meteor server code using "email 1.1.16 package" sends that page over to my email successfully but I receive the row html string.

It is a report which I wish to view and maybe print, it would be nice if it is a pdf attachment so that I can just click to open it, or be able to view the page in a different tab.
how can I go about fixing this problem? Thanks

```
Email.send({
        to: "abc@xyz.com",
        from: "aaa@bbb.com",
        subject: "My report",
        text: rowHtml
      });
```

**edit**
After ready Vasil's answer,  the [Blaze.toHTML](http://docs.meteor.com/api/blaze.html#Blaze-toHTML) "Renders a template or View to a string of HTML".
But I already have a html string, why do I need to convert it to html string again?.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = Blaze.toHTML(Blaze.With(data, function() { return Template.my_template; }));
Email.send({
        to: "abc@xyz.com",
        from: "aaa@bbb.com",
        subject: "My report",
        text: html
      });
```

> [Using dynamic HTML templates in Meteor emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845932/using-dynamic-html-templates-in-meteor-emails)

Comment: But where does the `rowHtml` go in this solution? Is this a complete answer?  what is `data` and `my_template` in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

All what I had to do is to change the line `text: rowHtml` to `html: rowHtml` according to the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html#Email-send)

```
Email.send({
    to: "abc@xyz.com",
    from: "aaa@bbb.com",
    subject: "My report",
    html: rowHtml
  });
```